# Exporting Layout View as GeoTIFF controlling resolution and size with Python?

Tags: arcpy, python, geotiff-tiff, export, resolution

I have two data frames ("Final" and "OverviewMap1") on one Layout View and I can't export them as a whole in one GeoTIFF. What is wrong with the following script:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\gnowak\Desktop\Fredropol_FINALv3.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Final", "OverviewMap1")[0]
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, r"C:\Users\gnowak\Desktop\Fredropol.tif", df,
                           df_export_width=1346,
                           df_export_height=1003,
                           geoTIFF_tags=True)
del mxd
```

Edit:

The following script works but I want to export GeoTIFF layout and want to setup resolution, width and height of tif.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"C:\Project\Output\Project.pdf")
del mxd
```

Answer (score 1):

The first question is about not being able to export the layout view as whole. This is because

```
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Final", "OverviewMap1")[0]
```

is an individual dataframe (a [DataFrame](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm) object). Instead you should use the data_frame parameter as `"PAGE_LAYOUT"` (default) to export the map document's page layout.

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\gnowak\Desktop\Fredropol_FINALv3.mxd")
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, r"C:\Users\gnowak\Desktop\Fredropol.tif", data_frame = "PAGE_LAYOUT", geoTIFF_tags=True)

del mxd
```

<sub>you can also omit `data_frame = "PAGE_LAYOUT"` in the above code.</sub>

The second question is that you want to control width, height and resolution in the exported file.

It is possible to use the parameter `resolution`:

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, r"C:\Users\gnowak\Desktop\Fredropol.tif", resolution = 100, geoTIFF_tags=True)
```

but width and height needs to be pre-authored. The [ExportToTIFF](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttotiff.htm) documentation says:

> df_export_width: ... . Exporting a page layout uses the map document page width instead of df_export_width.

Note that `pageSize` property in the  [MapDocument](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/mapdocument-class.htm) class is 'Read Only'.

In this [ESRI thread](https://community.esri.com/thread/70485) it is discussed that being able to change the map document size with Python would be complicated to implement.

On the other hand, there is the [SetPageSize](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/setpagesize-function.htm) function which will allow customizing the page size of an input map document. Maybe you can use it at the beginning of your workflow?